# Vaadin improve table rendering speed

Tags: java, performance, vaadin

Im kinda new to the fantastic Vaadin framwork so I got a perhaps trivial question.
Im loading a simple table with information from our databas. This takes way to long, like 10 sec, the response from the DB is very fast, where talking about 1000 rows with a response time of 2-3 ms but the actual rendering/painting from vaadin makes this very slow.

As a container we use BeanItemContainer with objects so that we can add what ever kind of beans we want. On the table itself we have set setCacheRate(10);

Anyone got any idés on how to speed things up ?

Best Regards
Marthin

Comment: Set the cacheRate to something like 1 or 2 (the default), that will definitely improve the speed. The cache rate means how many pages before and after the visible rows should be rendered on the client, so a bigger number means more elements to render.

Comment: This didn't help us unfortunately. I think we might have a problem in the the way we a little to often use requestRepaint. Thx for the advice though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems most of the rendering speed could be improved by trying to avoiding using requestRepaint in my action handlers. This does however mean that some of my interactions will not show immediatly but this is something we I live with.